# Import gzipped css files into html header?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gzip

To increase my website response time, I'm trying to use gzipped css and js files. I've
created style.css.gz file for my wordpress website, but couldn't import it. I copied both
style.css and style.css.gz files into the required directory, but it is not importing the
files. I've changed the .htaccess files. The online tool   whatsmyip.org shows me that server is ready for sending gzipped files to
the browser, but through gzipwtf.org the style.css is shown as unzipped.
Can someone help me how to import this file into my webpage. Currently I'm importing it as:

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/WP-Answers-Theme/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gzip compression via your htaccess file itself. it can be processed without gripping the files yourself. Just add the following to your htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```